# Django: get the path to the current django app

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app with some management commands. In one of those commands, I need to write a log file which is located in /logs allong side views.py, models.py, etc ...

Considering that my management command script is in /management/commands/mycommand.py, is there any reliable way to determine the location of the appdir from within mycommand.py ?

PS: by reliable, I mean without using `os.path.abspath( __file__ )`, because the location of the file might change later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what your settings are for.

Add this to your settings

```
MY_APP_LOG_DIRECTORY = "path/to/logs"
```

In your view functions, use

```
from django.conf import settings
```

Now you can use `settings.MY_APP_LOG_DIRECTORY` all you want.

Comment: That was so straight forward, I'm ashamed that I've asked :(. Can i delete the question? :))

Comment: @Nicolae Surdu: Don't delete it.  Others may have the same question.  Just accept the answer and move on.

Comment: I was kidding with the delete ... is just that sometimes I don't see the forest because of the trees :P